# M Function is not working in Power Query Editor

Tags: powerbi, custom-function

I am adding a custom column in Power BI through Power Query Editor.

My M function is not working, could you please help?

Number.ToText([engine_serial_num]) is working fine
(Text.Start(Number.ToText([claim_year]),4)) is also working fine

but when I am combining them, it is not working.

Number.ToText([engine_serial_num]) &
"_" & (Text.Start(Number.ToText([claim_year]),4))

[image]

Comment: show us the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Text.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-combine)

```
= Text.Combine({Number.ToText([engine_serial_num]), "_", Text.Start(Number.ToText([claim_year]),4)})
```

Also ensure that none of your results are returning blanks, and claim_year is always longer than 4 digits. You may have to add guard conditions around these depending on your data.